# Allocating 2d array of chars

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, memory-management, new-operator

#### Constructor

This is how I'm allocating it:

```
char **board = new char*[width];
for(i = 0; i < width; i++){
    board[i] = new char[height];
    for(j = 0; j < height; j++)
        board[i][j] = 0;
}
this->board = &board;
```

Inside the class, it's:

```
char ***board;
```

---

#### Destructor:

Now I want to delete it, so I wrote this (the board it the class field):

```
for(i = 0; i < width; i++)
    delete (*board)[i];
delete (*board);
```

---

When running this:

```
Board* b = new Board(16, 30, 99);
delete b;
```

I get an Unhandled exception. Why?

Comment: the Unhandled exception is caught when i'm entering the destructor

Comment: Both `delete` should be `delete[]`.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just using `std:vector<std::string>(width)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are storing a pointer to a variable on the stack, which becomes invalid as soon as the constructor returns. You should declare your class's data member as `char **board` and assign `this->board = board`.

**EDIT:** See also @Kerrek SB's comment. The local variable is redundant. Just use the data member directly (without the `this->`).

**EDIT 2:** Rectangular arrays are best created as a single array, using pointer arithmetic to index (which is what the compiler does with declared 2D arrays anyway):

```
char *board;
...
board = new char[width*height];
for(i = 0; i < width*height; ++i){
    board[i] = 0;
}
...
char& operator()(int i, int j) { return board[width*i + j]; }
```

This has the advantage of requiring just one memory allocation (and therefore one `delete[]`). It also improves cache locality because the cells are contiguous.

Even better, if you know the dimensions at compile-time, use templates:

```
template <int W, int H>
class Board {
    char board[W][H];
    ...
};
...
Board<8, 8>* b = new Board<8, 8>(...);
```

This requires no memory allocation at all (other than the `new Board`, of course).

Comment: Or even just use `board` from the start, without the local variable. Moral: Any time you see `***` in C++, you're doing it wrong :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Anytime you see a `**` in **C++**... you're *still* doing it wrong. ;)

Comment: @muntoo: Personally I agree -- though you *might* still be talking to an old C interface, so I wanted to go easy. Actually, I'd even go as far as saying that everytime you use a naked pointer, you should think again :-)

Comment: @Vlad: I should turn this around and ask "why do you want to use pointers?" C++ offers a wide selection of classes and idioms that cover almost everything you might want to do with pointers, and the result is often more robust, more correct and more flexible.

Comment: Well.. I see I over used the pointers, and ** is what I really need.. but you didn't mention the delete[] mistake which is important too.

Comment: EDIT2: it's the some amount of space, but it's more complicated and there maybe no continues space to allocate this.. no?

Comment: @Vlad: Multiple allocations require slightly more space due to the overhead of each allocation. Contiguous memory isn't an issue for systems with virtual memory, though contiguous address-space might be if you want to allocate a 1 GB array.

Answer (score 3):

Anything that you `new` you need to `delete`, in the exact same way:

```
board = new char*[width];
...
board[i] = new char[height];
...
...
delete[] board[i];
delete[] board;
```

No dereferencing is needed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the powers of C++.

```
class Board
{
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> board;

public:
    Board(std::vector<std::vector<char>> const& board) : board(board) {}

    Board(size_t x, size_t y, char val = 0)
    {
        std::vector<char> x2(x, val);
        this->board(y, x2);
    }
};
```

All you've got to do now is `board[y].push_back(char_x_val)` in order to append a new element to the end. You can treat `board[y][x]` just like any other 2D array (well, almost), but not worry about the deallocation.

Read up more on vectors [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/). (Anyone know a good tutorial?)

Comment: @Vlad Why not? It's certainly a lot easier to use. Are you worried it's "too complicated"?

Comment: Any chance, you mean `Board(std::vector<std::vector<char> > const& board) : board(board) {}` instead of your first ctor?

Comment: No.. I just like it when I wrote all the code. And it's really a lot more complicated then you think.. it's doing lot's of things you don't need(Microsoft...). Writing data structures on your own is always better, unless you're lazy and don't care about complexity..

Comment: @Vlad: No, no, no. Not at all. I'm sorry, but everything in your last comment is just plain wrong.

Comment: @Vlad What does Microsoft have to do with this...? Also, [reinventing the wheel](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-unless-you-plan-on-learning-more-about-wheels.html) [badly] every time leaves room for errors, unless you don't care about ease of use [for others *and* yourself], and a whole lot of other things. As the article says, if you spend less time reinventing the wheel, you can spend more time creating bicycles and other works of art! Complexity that can be avoided **should** be avoided. (I can't remember the appropriate Coding Horror article for that one.)

Comment: Whoah. I used up the 600 character limit in that last comment *exactly*! (Including the markup.)

Comment: maybe.. but all I need here is a 2D array(which is [][] and nothing is new here), I'm not reinventing anything, and I don't need resizeble arrays... btw I'm missing: what exactly I'm reinventing??

Comment: @Vlad You're "reinventing" dynamic memory allocation using `new`, when you could just be using the easier `std::vector`. The "wheel" we're talking about here is hard to define, but just trust us - `std::vector`s are the way to go here.

Comment: it's really funny to read my own comments after a few years, I can't seem to recognize my opinions at all

Comment: @Vladp If I read something I had written a year ago, I sometimes think, "wtf was this really me"?

Comment: @SicariusNoctis exactly